# ID毎の開始地点と終了地点のデータから各地点毎でIDをカウントする方法

Tags: sql

以下のようなID毎の開始地点と終了地点のデータがあった場合、
各地点毎での有効なID数をSQLで集計する方法を考えているのですが
いまいちいい方法が思いつきませんどなたかよい方法を教えていただけないでしょうか？

ID毎の開始地点と終了地点のデータ
ID,start,end
1,0,3
2,1,3
3,2,3
4,0,1
5,1,2

地点毎でのID集計
0地点:2人(1,4)
1地点:4人(1,2,4,5)
2地点:4人(1,2,3,5)
3地点:3人(1,2,3)

※前提としては開始地点と終了地点は時間軸等の連続性あるものとします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL でクロスジョインを使ってみました。

```
# 適当なテーブルを作成
CREATE TABLE id_tbl (ID int, start int, end int);
# insert data
SELECT * FROM id_tbl;
+------+-------+------+
| ID   | start | end  |
+------+-------+------+
|    1 |     0 |    3 |
|    2 |     1 |    3 |
|    3 |     2 |    3 |
|    4 |     0 |    1 |
|    5 |     1 |    2 |
+------+-------+------+

# query
SELECT C AS POINT, COUNT(C) AS COUNT, GROUP_CONCAT(ID) AS PERSONS FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT(C) FROM (
    SELECT start AS C FROM id_tbl UNION ALL SELECT end AS C FROM id_tbl
  ) AS _ ORDER BY C
) AS _ CROSS JOIN id_tbl AS B ON C >= B.start and C <= B.end GROUP BY C;
=>
+-------+-------+---------+
| POINT | COUNT | PERSONS |
+-------+-------+---------+
|     0 |     2 | 1,4     |
|     1 |     4 | 1,2,4,5 |
|     2 |     4 | 1,2,3,5 |
|     3 |     3 | 1,2,3   |
+-------+-------+---------+
```

Comment: 頂いたヒントで解決できました！Google Bigquery を使っているのでCROSS JOINで不等号が使えないのでフラグを立てる形に読み替えました。

SELECT
  A.POINT AS POINT,
  COUNT(PERSON) AS COUNT,
  GROUP_CONCAT(PERSON) AS PERSONS
FROM
  (
  SELECT
    *,
    IF(A.POINT BETWEEN B.S AND B.E,B.I,null) AS PERSON
  FROM
    (
    SELECT
      POINT
    FROM
     (SELECT S AS POINT FROM [id_tbl]),
     (SELECT E AS POINT FROM [id_tbl])
    GROUP BY
      POINT
    ORDER BY
      POINT
    ) AS A
  CROSS JOIN
    [id_tbl] AS B
  )
GROUP BY
  POINT